# Define today's date in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a **use case report** on Power Bi for 2018-2019.
I used many date functions as isInCurrentYear, isInCurrentMonth...

But today's date always change (normal)... So I would like to fix it.

For example, I would like that the today date is 30/03/2019. And never change.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To define today's date it will be:
DAX: [TODAY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/today-function-dax)
M: [DateTime.LocalNow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-localnow) or [DateTime.FixedLocalNow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-fixedlocalnow)

For M just to get the date part use DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())

You can then format or extract the relevant part of the date using DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) , and use an IF clause to check if it todays date

In M calculated colum

```
if [Your date column] = DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) then "Current Date" else "Not Current Day
```

You can set a fixed date using [Date.FromText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-fromtext)
for example:

```
Date.FromText("2010-12-31")
```

You can also set a date using a parameter, and reference that in the query

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi,  I do not want to get the current date, I know how to do it. I would like to know how to fix it on a specific date.

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer, if you could clarify your question, why you need to set the date that may help